# the web server certificate template could not be duplicated. Access Is denied

Tags: certificate, windows-server-2016

> Windows Server 2016, ADFS, Certification Authority

I tried to create duplicate web server template, but it says that it's not an accessible. see below snap.

[image]

Now, My client is not technical, he provide me an account with most of the access, account is not an administrator, but I can assign many access to my self using AD Administrative service.

**My only question is which access DO I need to provide to this account for creating duplicate web server certificate template?**

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-domain environment, I have had the same issue, if I did not select a domain controller in the root domain, respectively in the domain that hosts the CA. In my case, another domain was chosen by the console, because my computer for remote administration is in another domain (child domain).

Try the following:

1. Open "Certificate Template Console"
2. Right-click "Certificate Templates" in the left pane
3. Click "Connect to another writable domain controller ..."
4. Change the domain
5. click "Ok"

Try to duplicate once again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but thought I might add a fix that could help others. The account you use to login to the CA server should have Enterprise admin rights and should also be a member of local IIS_IUSRS group. If you have verified both, just logout and login to the box again and you should be able to duplicate a template.